# Problems with TCP/IP in Lua

Tags: sockets, tcp, lua, server

I am doing a project that is related with creating TCP/IP communication in Lua language. My computer is going to be a server and I wanna connect it with another computer.

So, here is the code:

```
local socket = require'socket'
local server = socket.tcp()
server:bind('*', 7200)
server:listen(32)
>>>>local client = server:accept() 
--Here I have a problem. It is not working. 
--It says:
--calling 'accept' on bad self (tcp{server} expected,got userdata in function)
client:settimeout(10)
 -- receive the line
 local line, err = client:receive()
  -- if there was no error, send it back to the client
 if not err then 
 client:send('test') --end
  -- done with client, close the object
  client:close()
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works: If I add an `end` at the bottom of your code it works for me.